# updating belongs to relationship laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'd like to improve this piece of code when updating a related model (1 to 1) on laravel and also know if this is right, wrong, right but not recommended, etc. Thanks all.

```
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->update();

    $tenant = Tenant::where('user_id', $id)->first();
    $tenant->suite_number = $request->input('suite_number');
    $tenant->update();
```

Comment: Any problems with your code? Looks fine to me. You might want to try `$tenant = $user->tenant;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to define relationship of user and tenant in you user model:

```
// User.php
public function tenant()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Tenant');
}
```

As this is an one to one model, you can update your related model like following. Make sure the relation model also exists.

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->name = $request->input('name');
$user->email = $request->input('email');
$user->tenant->suite_number = $request->input('suite_number');
$user->push();
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe it could be

```
// you can omit the input() if u want to
$user = User::find($id);
$user->update([
    'name' => $request->name;
    'email' => $request->email;    
]);

$tenant = Tenant::where('user_id', $id)->first();
$tenant->update([
    'suite_number' => $request->suite_number;
]);
```

for eager loading it would be

```
$user = User::with('tenant')->find($id);
$user->update([
    'name'                => $request->name;
    'email'               => $request->email;   
    'tenant.suite_number' => $request->suite_number;
]);
```

or reverse relation

```
$tenant = Tenant::with('user')->where('user_id', $id)->first();
$tenant->update([
    'suite_number' => $request->suite_number;
    'user.name'    => $request->name;
    'user.email'   => $request->email;  
]);
```